# Length of line segment in diagram

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> **Question: Consider the diagram below.  How can one express the length of $z$ in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$ without including $x$ in the expression?** If it is impossible to express $z$ in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$ alone, please answer with an explanation of why.

[image: This is the diagram.]

**More Information:** $ax$ and $bx$ are angles, where $x$ is some constant and $a$ and $b$ are each being multiplied by it. In other words, the two angles are in ratio $a$ to $b$. You can assume that $a$ is greater than $b$ and both $ax$ and $bx$ are less than 90 degrees. $c$ is the length of the line segment along the diagram's base.

**Motivation:** I'm asking this question because I feel that the constraints on the diagram are sufficient to bind $z$ to a single value for given $a$, $b$, and $c$. That is, I suspect knowing the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ (and knowing the other lengths I have specified) one should be able to determine $z$ with certainty.

Thus, I suspect it is likely $z$ can be expressed in terms of only $a$, $b$, and $c$. Unfortunately, all my attempts to derive an expression for $z$ have ended up with me including $x$ in my expression or just churning out tautologies. Clearly help is needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps it is notable that $c = \sin(ax) + \sin(bx)$.

Comment: Also, $z = 2 \sin(\frac{(a + b)x}{2})$

Comment: Also, 
$$
z^2 = c^2 + (\cos(bx) - \cos(ax))^2
$$

Comment: Definitely all important observations! Also, there are a number of similar triangles (3 it looks like) scattered throughout the bottom half of the diagram. I've tried to mess with those, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [asked Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos(2x%2F5)+-+cos(x)+where+sin(2x%2F5)%2Bsin(x)+%3D+1)
to find $\cos\left(\frac25x\right) - \cos(x) = 1$
(the square root of $z^2 - c^2$)
where $\sin\left(\frac25x\right) + \sin(x) = 1$.
It told me the exact forms are roots of a ninth-degree polynomial.

Setting $b = \frac23$ instead of $\frac25$ 
resulted in a fifth-degree polynomial,
while $b = \frac27$ resulted in one of the thirteenth degree.

I don't think you're ever going to find
a useful closed formula that will work for $a$ and $b$ in general.
I would recommend a numeric approach: find an approximate solution for $x$
in $\sin(ax) + \sin(bx) = c$ to any degree of accuracy you want.
This should be easy enough to do (for example by the bisection method),
because $\sin(ax) + \sin(bx)$ is a strictly increasing function 
from $x=0$ to $x=\frac\pi{2a}$.
Moreover, it works for arbitrary values of $a$ and $b$, not just ones
such that $\frac ba$ is a ratio of integers with a small denominator.

Once you have a value of $x$, use it to compute 
$$z = \sqrt{c^2 + (\cos(bx) - \cos(ax))^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let's call $d$ the height of the rectangle, then:

$$d=(d+e)-e=\cos (bx)-\cos (ax) \quad (1)$$

we also know that

$$p+q=\sin (ax)+ \sin (bx)=c \quad (2)$$

then

$$z^2=d^2+c^2=2(1-\cos [x(a+b)])$$

From $(2)$ we can hope to find $x$ once $a,b,c$ are properly given. Once we find $x$ as a function of $a,b,c$ then $z$ doesn't depend on $x$.

The big problem is solve $(2)$. We can prove if there is a solution once we know $a,b,c$ but find a close formula I don't know if it is possible.

For example: how to find the solution for:

$$\sin(11x)+\sin(61x)=0.1234$$

That will be (roughly speaking) a $61$ degree polynomial and we should find a roots for it.

What I can say is the following:

*If we know $a,b,c$ then we can say if $(2)$ has a solution. If there is a solution then $z$ doesn't depends on $x$. Find a close formula is something that I can't assure. Probably you will need a numerial method to find an approximation.*